# Does $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f)$ implies $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)$ exists?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, asymptotics

Let $f,g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be continuous function, and recall that $f=O(g)$ if there exists $C>0$ such that for sufficiently large $x$, we have $f(x)\leq Cg(x)$, and define $g=O(f)$ similarly. I found a statement that says

> There exists $L\in \mathbb{R}, |L|<\infty$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=L$ if and only if $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f)$.

Is this statement correct? It is easy to see that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=L$ implies $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f)$. What about the other implication? Is it wrong or is it provable? If provable, I would appreciate any comments on how to prive it.

Comment: $f=2+cos(x)$ and $g=2 + sin(x)$. I always have $f<4g$ and $g<4f$. However $f/g$ does not converge. EDIT: Ninjae'd!

Comment: Thanks guys! I was trying to come up with counterexamples but I didn't expect it to be so easy!

Comment: @Martigan Please leave yours up, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Martigan  I think you should write that as an answer.

Comment: modify to $f=1+cos(x)$, $g=1$ from Martigan example

Comment: @Tim: That example does fullfull $g=O(f)$, as $f$ has inifinitely many zeros.

Answer (score 1):

$f=2+\cos(x)$ and $g=2+\sin(x)$.

I always have $f<4g$ and $g<4f$.

However $f/g$ does not converge